# I can't get a python prompt on ESP8266/nodemcu with micropython

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I've flashed several different versions of micropython onto my ESP8266/nodemcu board and I keep getting the following output in a terminal:
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0x00
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x01,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x04
mode:QIO, clock div:2
cmd len 2
ets_main.c 371 
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

These messages repeat continuously.  I've tried both with and without -fm dio and -fm qio.  When I hit the flash button, it indicates on the terminal it's ready for download at which time I run the esptool.py to flash the micropython.

Answer (score 0):

Are You trying it on Windows, Mac or Linux?

I've recently had some problems with the NodeMcu and Micrpython as well and therefore set up a pretty easy to read and straightforward documentation [python2nodemcu](https://github.com/pixelstuermer/python2nodemcu) on GitHub (what I would call an end-to-end documentation).

Please have a look at it and then verify the following (short version of the link above):

- Do You have Python3 installed?

  - Run `python --version`
  - Or `python3 --version`
- Do You have the proper driver installed for serial USB-to-UART connection?

  - See [here](https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers)
- Do You know the device file name, which represents the interface of Your device?

  - Give it a try with `ls -la /dev/tty.*`
- Do You have the most recent MicroPython firmware?

  - You also need the [correct one for the NodeMcu](http://micropython.org/download#esp8266)
- I guess, [EspTool](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) and [PySerial](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial) are installed properly?
- Can You delete the flash without an error?

  - Try `python3 esptool.py --port /dev/tty.{device-file} erase_flash`
- Does the most simple flashing command (without parameters) work?

  - Try `python3 esptool.py --port /dev/tty.{device-file} write_flash 0x00000 {latest-micropython-firmware-for-node-mcu}.bin`
- Did You try to connect to the REPL prompt?

  - Try `screen /dev/tty.{device-file} 115200`
  - Maybe try different baud rates, depending on Your driver, cable, etc.
- Did You try to connect to the board using [Ampy](https://github.com/scientifichackers/ampy)?

  - E.g., You can list the files on Your device using `python3 ampy/cli.py --port /dev/tty.{device-file} --baud 115200 ls`
  - Again, maybe try other baud rates

Next to this, can You:

- Flash the board with the [default firmware](https://nodemcu-build.com/)?
- Connect to it with some 3rd party software, such as [EspLorer](https://esp8266.ru/esplorer) or [CoolTherm](https://freeware.the-meiers.org/)?

As of my experience, You do not necessarily need to push the physical flash button on the device. Just run the `erase_flash` and then the `flash` command as stated above.